# How to verify node.js version (other than node -v)

Tags: node.js

I have this strange issue, where I am using 10th version of node (10.9.0) on a server, but things that should work or be supported in that version, are not.
For example, according to [this table](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-Object-static-methods-Object-values), this version supports `Object.values()`. On my local node installation - this indeed works, but on server, where I don't have much freedom about what software I am using, it does not.

Is there any way to truly verify used node version (`node -v` shows 10.9.0 as written above)? Maybe it's only a version of main binary yet all libs it's using are from version 6 (that one is also installed on that server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `process` object that Node.js exposes has a lot of information including the version.

```
console.log(process.version); // v10.9.0
```

You can find the [Node.js `process.verison` documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version).

So within your application you can run that to see if it's truly what you expect.

You can also try running `which node` on your server. That should print the path it's using to find node. If you have multiple copies or installations of node, it might be using a path that is outdated. Making sure your path is up to date will solve that problem, and `which node` can help debug that.

Comment: Thanks, nice one but it also says 10.9.0 :/ `which node` is not very helpful, as it's always showing same alias path. Anyway, I've just found source of my issue, but I am yet to find a way to solve it. I am using WinSCP to upload files from local project to server and sometimes I am using it to run bash scripts to build something with node as well. It seems that when I am doing that through WinSCP and not with standard ssh client (putty or now ubuntu for windows) it is really using v6 instead of v10. I am not sure how to solve this issue (other than run scripts "directly" ;) ).

Comment: @SoulReaver I'm not sure why `WinSCP` would be using Node.js directly.  Shouldn't it just be running the commands you tell it to or something? Seems like you have control over that process. But I could be totally wrong.

Comment: it is not using it directly. I have simple bash script with `node somescript.js` inside (+ bashy preamble of course). I am running this script from `WinSCP`. Now, I've added `node -v > nodev.txt` to this script and found out that `WinSCP` for some reason is the culprit. strangely, using same account it gives different results when I log in through SSH directly (then nodev file contents will show v10)